# Recommended bash key bindings in .inputrc file?

Tags: bash, unix, inputrc

I have a few simple key bindings such as reverse-search-history.  I saw an article a while ago with some other great ideas for key bindings.  Was wondering what other people out there had configured.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's the list](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_93.html).

Which of these are "useful" is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I didn't realize there was a definitive list.  Cheers!